# What are the appropriate phrases to use to wish an astronaut safe travels?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, safety, astronauts, language

When you want to wish an astronaut "safe travels", what particular phrases are commonly used?

I'm looking for historical phrases as well as more modern.

Although I'm more interested in English phrases, answers for all languages are welcome, as long as you provide an English translation

Comment: I can say one fact about Russian cosmonauts. Most of them don't like to tell and hear about their "last" spaceflight ("последний" in Russian). Yes, it's some superstitious -  don't call flight the "last" one or you can die. They prefer the word like "edge" flight ("крайний"). So it's preferable to not say something like "I wish you a success in your last flight". Actually, most Russian aircraft pilots have this custom too. I don't know is the custom widespread between non-Russian astronauts and pilots...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Have a good flight" works.

"Godspeed" is traditional in the US space program, not necessarily as a religious reference, but because [Scott Carpenter said it to John Glenn](https://www.pennlive.com/midstate/2013/10/scott_carpenter_delivered_the.html).

Here's a sign from the training team at the STS-135 crew sendoff at Ellington Field. (July 4, 2011)

[image]

(personal photo)

Comment: Nice touch with a personal photo!

Comment: "Flamey-end down"

Comment: ["I hope you go to space today."](https://xkcd.com/1133/)

Comment: OM, tried to PM you, but unable to figure that out...in any event, perhaps you could help me out. I was in MCC during the STS-95 launch and can distinctly remember Scott Horowitz saying "Godspeed" on the loops at some point. However, youtube vids of said launch indicate that Susan Still was the A&E CAPCOM that day. Am I descending further into senility?

Comment: @Digger Have no fear! Shuttle MIssions Summary https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/outreach/SignificantIncidents/assets/space-shuttle-missions-summary.pdf page 2-112 shows Still **& Horowitz** as CAPCOMs.

Comment: @Digger https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/shuttle/sts-95/html/s98_16165.html